Trouble adding a listener to a button during runtime in Unity
I am trying to add a listener to a button when a method is ran in Unity.
[SerializeField] private CraftTextController craftTextController;
[SerializeField] private int index;

private void Purchase()
{
    button.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    button.onClick.AddListener(craftTextController.DisplayItemText(index));
}

In another script I have,
public void DisplayItemText(int index)
{
    // code
}

To code is returning an error on the AddListener, "cannot convert from 'void' to 'UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction'
Thank your any help and let me know if more code is needed.

I think the error is rather complaining about the entire signature.
Your method is taking a parameter
void DisplayItemText(int index)

while UnityAction is a parameterless
delegate void UnityAction()


You want e.g.
// Using an ad-hoc Lambda expression 
button.onClick.AddListener(() => craftTextController.DisplayItemText(index));

or - this is in particular important if you want to unsubscribe as well - store the lambda expression itself in a class field
private UnityAction clickAction;

...

clickAction = () => craftTextController.DisplayItemText(index);

button.onClick.AddListener(clickAction);

or have a proper named wrapper method
button.onClick.AddListener(OnButtonClicked);

...

private void OnButtonClicked()
{
    craftTextController.DisplayItemText(index);
}


Learn more about delegates and lambda expressions
